# USB wifi adapter very slow

Tags: wireless-networking, router, usb

I am using https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6283840?p=speedtest&visit_id=637492003779105601-2311545527&rd=1 to test my network speed.
On my macbook air, the download speed over wifi is about 350MBPS, however, on my desktop which connects to the modem via a usb wifi adaptor, it is only about 25MBPS.

This is the USB adaptor I am using. According to the specification, it should have at least 200MBPS
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07P5PRK7J/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P5PRK7J)

I test this at the same location, the direct distance from the modem is around 30 feet.

What could be causing this huge difference?

Comment: I wanted to test the usb wifi adaptor on my mac, but I don't know how to turn off the build-in wifi and make sure it is using the usb adaptor to connect.

Comment: The adapter specifications don't make sense.  WiFI 5 is only 5 GHz.  What is the access point specifications?

Comment: If by "access point" you mean my home internet specification, mine is verizon fios 940MBPS, the router looks like this one https://www.walmart.com/ip/Verizon-FiOS-G3100-Wireless-router-4-port-switch-GigE-802-11ax-MoCA-2-5-WAN-ports-2-802-11a-b-g-n-ac-ax-Tri-Band/825140955?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=101011629&&adid=22222222227343257296&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=430226630807&wl4=pla-897238876716&wl5=9004370&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=218903643&wl11=online&wl12=825140955&veh=sem&gclid=CjwKCAiAmrOBBhA0EiwArn3mfEeRlq8YfTDcV2Ry3kPeEAP1_MW6mbLC_mFVLHgzXTz-Z0_saVtgchoC4ukQAvD_BwE

Comment: The access point is the modem/router/gateway.  Does your Macbook Air have WIFi 5 or WiFi 6?

Comment: Don't know how to check but it is 2020's version

Comment: You should use a wired connection for your desktop computer, WiFi adapter should be connected to PCIe bus, USB is much slower than PCIe.

Comment: So the bottleneck is USB's connection speed? But even USB2.0 has 480Mbps speed. How come my download speed is way lower than this?